# Illegal hardware instruction, dSYM failed to upload-symbols

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I've searched for a similar problem on google but didn't find exactly what I face. I've ever uploaded dSYMs in Firebase before and used the same command

`/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs`

, but when I try to do it again on other days, now it says that:

`[1]    13901 illegal hardware instruction   -gsp  -p ios /Users/jeffry_sandy/Downloads/appDsyms.zip~`

(*number **13901** keep changing whenever I try to upload the file*), I'm using Mac OS Monterey, and XCode Version 12.5 (12E262).

I use the same format before that works with me, I still didn't understand what this illegal hardware meant, I try to run as admin, and still doesn't work. Can anyone help me please..